# Enabling panning in google maps integration after automatic marker centering

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've set up a google maps integration with my own custom map and markers dynamically placed by the backend on page load.

The problem is that my code centers the map on the marker, and if you try to pan the map anywhere it will re-position the map to the centered marker repeatedly (you are allowed to zoom in/out but not pan).

The map centering is handled as follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function (map) {
    var coords = genCoords(map,"40.014","80.52");

    clueLocation = new google.maps.Marker({
        map:map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat(),coords.lng()),
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat(),coords.lng()),
        title: 'Ramara du Croissant'
    });
    map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat(),coords.lng()) );
}.bind(null,map));
```

And I have also made a [live version](http://beta.rstt.net/clue/Arr-So-I-am-a-crust-and/) available where the behavior can be experienced

If it does make a difference, the code in question will always show only a single marker, what I've discovered so far are boundary solutions when you need to center the map within a set array of markers which isn't the approach I'm going for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that my code centers the map on the marker, and if you
>   try to pan the map anywhere it will re-position the map to the
>   centered marker repeatedly (you are allowed to zoom in/out but not
>   pan).

well, of course. you are listening to the `idle` event, and that is what happens after you pan the map.

[image: idle]

The `idle` event is triggered whenever the map is finished redrawing after a scroll or zoom change.

Comment: Wow, thank you, I should have thought that bit a bit more through before I did it I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the map to center on the marker once, use [google.maps.event.addListenerOnce](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener), rather than google.maps.event.addListener

You may want to reevaluate using the idle event for this purpose, but if you are only going to show a single marker, it should work.